# Dspace not displaying page even though the installation worked

Tags: java, tomcat, dspace

I followed the following steps for installing dspace

```
1) Installed Java 1.6 and path was set in system variable as well as the user variable `JAVA_HOME`
2) Unzipped apache ant 1.9.4 and apache maven 3.2.3 and saved in C:/ drive
3) The path was set for apache ant and apache maven in system variables as well as user variable  `ANT_HOME` was created
4) Installed Postgresql 8.4.22-1 and connected to postgres database, created a new login role and a new database called dspace
5) Installed Apache Tomcat 6.0.41 and the service was started
6) Copied dspace 3.1 src release in C:/ drive and created a folder C:/dspace for dspace installation
7) In the dspace.cfg file following values were set:
    a) dspace.dir = C:\dspace-3.1-src-release\dspace  (have set this path coz nothing gets installed to C:/dspace folder although its specified in the manual)
    b) dspace.hostname = the host URL
    c) dspace.baseUrl = the host URL port 8080
    d) dspace.url = the host URL port 8080/jspui
    e) dspace.name = "Digital Library"
    f) db.name = postgres
    g) db.url = jdbc:postgresql://localhost port 5432/dspace
    h) db.driver = org.postgresql.Driver
    i) db.username = dspace
       db.password = dspace
8) Through the command prompt changed the directory to C:\dspace-3.1-src-release\dspace and 
9) the command mvn package was run message "BUILD SUCCESSFUL" was displayed
10) During the execution of the command mvn package several files were downloaded to C:\dspace-3.1-src-release\dspace\target
11) Through the command prompt changed the directory to C:\dspace-3.1-src-release\dspace\target\dspace-3.1-build and the command ant fresh_install was run (here the manual asks to run the command through    directory C:\dspace\bin but theres nothing installed to dspace folder and thus no bin too so it cant be run)
12) The build was successful
13) Through the command prompt changed the directory to C:\dspace-3.1-src-release\dspace\target\dspace-3.1-build\bin and the command dspace create-administrator was run
14) An administrator account was created successfully
15) Both the Postgres and Apache Tomcat server were started
16) The 3 folders jspui, xmlui and oai from dspace \ webapps… was copied and pasted these folders in C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 6.0\webapps
17) Through Mozilla Firefox localhost port 8080 /jspui/ was visited and 404 status error is found saying requested resource is not available
```

Comment: In your dspace.dir, don't use backslash, use forward slash and you should not install dspace in your source directory. Try this in your dspace.dir `dspace.dir = C:/dspace`

Comment: THanks euler...it worked...kindly post it as an answer...I will accept as helpful answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For windows users, the use of back slashes in path separators is easily overlooked during installation of DSpace. This is mentioned here: [DSpace Windows Installation](https://wiki.duraspace.org/display/DSDOC3x/Installation#Installation-WindowsInstallation)

- For all path separators use forward slashes (e.g. "/"). For example: "C:/dspace" is a valid Windows path.  But, be warned that "C:\dspace" IS INVALID and will cause errors.

Answer (score 0):

Try to make the mvn package from the C:\dspace-3.1-src-release\ directory and redo next steps.